# Как динамически создать button в Фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, button

Есть `fragment` в котором мне нужно динамически создать `button`.

```
Button btnNew;
btnNew = new Button(this);
btnNew.setText("Текст");
```

Но проблема в том, что подчеркивается `this` поскольку я создаю кнопку в Фрагменте. Что нужно использовать вместо `this`? Я думаю что ошибку можно сюда не писать, поскольку эта проблема для Вас итак будет понятная, я думаю.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте получить доступ из фрагмента методом ***getActivity***:

```
Button btnNew = new Button(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе `View` (к которым относится и кнопка) параметром требуется `Context`.
В активити контекстом может быть сама активити, так как является его потомком, поэтому в качестве контекста указывается служебное слово `this` (ссылка на текущий объект).
Фрагмент не является потомком контекста и ссылка на его текущий экземпляр (this) не подходит, однако у фрагмента имеется метод `getActivity()`, который возвращает экземпляр активити, в которой хостится фрагмент и это уже подходящий объект в качестве контекста.
Если в ваш фрагменте ранее был получен контекст, вы можете использовать его в качестве параметра для создания экземпляра `View`, а не обращаться к методу.